# Creating a nice-looking box without using minipage

Tags: tikz-pgf, boxes, counters, tcolorbox, newtheorem

I would like to create the following box and title without using  `minipage`
With :

- small box before Title
- Title with counter

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,fancybox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newtheorem{test}{Test}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

Comment rechercher l'ordre d'un élément d'un groupe 

\shadowbox{
\begin{minipage}[c]{7in}
\subsubsection{Méthode1.3}-Soit G un groupe, noté multiplicativement, et soit $a\in G$. Pour déterminer l'ordre de l'élément $a$, on peut:
\begin{itemize}
\item Calculer les puissances successives de l'élément $a$ jusqu'à l'obtention de l'élément neutre.
\item Trouver une propriété qui montre qu'aucune puissance de $a$  ne peut être le neutre.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

Here is another attempt :

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcounter{exa}

\tcbset{
myexample/.style={
  enhanced,
  colback=white,
  colframe=black,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
    breakable,
  drop shadow={black,opacity=1},
  sharp corners,
  titlerule=0pt,
  title={\refstepcounter{exa}\ding{111} Methode~\theexa.},
  title style={fill=white},
  coltitle=black,
  drop shadow,
  highlight math style={reset,colback=white,colframe=black}
  }
}

\newtcolorbox{EducBox}{myexample}

\begin{document}

\begin{EducBox}
\centering
Soit G un groupe, noté multiplicativement, et soit $a\in G$. Pour déterminer l'ordre de l'élément $a$, on peut:
\begin{itemize}
\item Calculer les puissances successives de l'élément $a$ jusqu'à l'obtention de l'élément neutre.
\item Trouver une propriété qui montre qu'aucune puissance de $a$  ne peut être le neutre.
\end{itemize}
\end{EducBox}

\end{document}
```

which produces :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a package like `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @TeXnician I read quickly this link https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf but I didn't find  a box like what I want

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `minipage`? What is the underlying goal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `tcolorbox` and its `tcbtheorems` is not too difficult.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bbding}

\tcbset{
    methstyle/.style={
        enhanced,
        theorem style=plain,
        sharp corners,
        colframe=black,
        colback=white,
        coltitle=black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\upshape,
        drop shadow={black,opacity=1},
        separator sign dash,
        before title=\SquareShadowBottomRight\ ,
    }
}

\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{Methode}{Méthode}{methstyle}{Met}


\begin{document}

Comment rechercher l'ordre d'un élément d'un groupe 

\section{Methodes}

\begin{Methode}{A new méthode}{anm}
Soit $G$ un groupe, noté multiplicativement, et soit $a\in G$. Pour déterminer l'ordre de l'élément $a$, on peut:
\begin{itemize}
\item Calculer les puissances successives de l'élément $a$ jusqu'à l'obtention de l'élément neutre.
\item Trouver une propriété qui montre qu'aucune puissance de $a$  ne peut être le neutre.
\end{itemize}
\end{Methode}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to forward the comment  @BambOo has made on my tcolorbox post: "You can also add opacity=1 to the drop shadow option to get a bit closer to the OP's demand :)". But great answer, +1.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @TeXnician for opacity thing. +1 very nice work Thank you

Comment: @TeXnician Done. Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: could you replace the \quare with a square with shadows like the picture That I post I try '\shadowbox' but with no luck I used pifont pakcage too but with no sucess

Comment: @Educ Do you know which symbol they use? I don't.

Comment: I don't but from the picture it's square with shadow

Comment: @Edut I've found something similar in `bbding`. If you don't like, try to find something else in [`The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) list

Comment: I found it in 'bbding' it's called '\SquareCastShadowBottomRight' Thank you again

Answer (score 6):

Here's a starter with tcolorbox. I do not have your section and subsection styles, so this is with default styles. Please note that the tcolorbox manual is no quick read, it requires some patience.

In the code example the box is drawn with optional arguments, but feel free to use `\newtcolorbox` instead if your original aim was to shorten the code.

[image: box]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced, sharp corners, colback=white, colframe=black, drop shadow={black,opacity=1}]
\subsubsection{Méthode1.3}
Soit G un groupe, noté multiplicativement, et soit $a\in G$. Pour déterminer l'ordre de l'élément $a$, on peut:
\begin{itemize}
\item Calculer les puissances successives de l'élément $a$ jusqu'à l'obtention de l'élément neutre.
\item Trouver une propriété qui montre qu'aucune puissance de $a$  ne peut être le neutre.
\end{itemize}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you but where is small box before title 'Methode'

Comment: Where is also counter ?

Comment: @Texnician, you can also add `opacity=1` to the `drop shadow` option to get a bit closer to the OP's demand :)

Comment: @Educ You do not provide your sectioning style (you're using a styled subsubsection for the picture as it seems), so I don't attempt to replicate it. As you are using a different setup to create the picture in your question than your MWE produces, I only try to give you a starter on the box you've asked for.

Answer (score 6):

Quick and dirty implementation of your box without any packages:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{duckuments}

\newsavebox\customboxbox
\newlength\customboxOuterWidth
\newlength\customboxOuterHeight
\newlength\customboxOuterDepth
\newlength\customboxInnerWidth
\newlength\customboxRuleWidth
\newlength\customboxShadowHeight
\newlength\customboxShadowDepth
\newlength\customboxShadowWidth
\newlength\customboxInnerSep

\customboxInnerSep3\fboxsep
\customboxRuleWidth.6pt
\customboxShadowWidth4pt

\newenvironment{custombox}[1][\linewidth]
  {%
    \noindent
    \customboxOuterWidth#1
    \advance\customboxOuterWidth-\customboxShadowWidth
    \customboxInnerWidth#1
    \advance\customboxInnerWidth-2\customboxRuleWidth
    \advance\customboxInnerWidth-2\customboxInnerSep
    \advance\customboxInnerWidth-\customboxShadowWidth
    \setbox\customboxbox\vbox\bgroup
      \hsize\customboxInnerWidth
      \linewidth\hsize
      \noindent
      \ignorespaces
  }
  {%
      \ifhmode\unskip\fi
    \egroup
    \customboxOuterHeight\ht\customboxbox
    \advance\customboxOuterHeight\customboxInnerSep
    \customboxOuterDepth\dp\customboxbox
    \advance\customboxOuterDepth\customboxInnerSep
    \customboxShadowHeight\customboxOuterHeight
    \advance\customboxShadowHeight-\customboxShadowWidth
    \customboxShadowDepth\customboxOuterDepth
    \advance\customboxShadowDepth\customboxShadowWidth
    \raisebox{\customboxOuterHeight}
      {\rlap{\vrule height \customboxRuleWidth width \customboxOuterWidth}}%
    \vrule height \customboxOuterHeight
           depth \customboxOuterDepth
           width \customboxRuleWidth
    \rlap
      {%
        \hskip\customboxInnerSep\usebox\customboxbox
        \hskip\customboxInnerSep
        \vrule height \customboxOuterHeight
               depth \customboxOuterDepth
               width \customboxRuleWidth
        \vrule height \customboxShadowHeight
               depth \customboxShadowDepth
               width \customboxShadowWidth
      }%
    \raisebox{-\customboxOuterDepth}
      {%
        \rlap
          {%
            \vrule height \customboxRuleWidth
                   depth 0pt
                   width \customboxOuterWidth
          }%
        \hskip\customboxShadowWidth
        \advance\customboxOuterWidth-\customboxRuleWidth
        \vrule height \customboxRuleWidth
               depth \customboxShadowWidth
               width \customboxOuterWidth
      }%
  }


\begin{document}
\begin{custombox}
  \blindduck
\end{custombox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The environment takes an optional argument which specifies the used total width. Content width is calculated based on total width, `\customboxInnerSep`, `\customboxRuleWidth` and `\customboxShadowWidth`.

It doesn't add any outer spacing.